# Dealing with multi-colineariality in multiple linear regression

Tags: linear-regression

I am trying to fit a multivariate regression model to unravel which immune cells and their subsets and cytokines that contribute to the development of arthritis. However, the problems are that many of them are highly correlated to each other. All of them are important variables and I am not keen to remove some of them out. Is there any logical and meaninful ways to deal with it? are there any non-parametric models you could suggest rather than fitting paramedic model which we need to obey to several assumptions of it. This is a pilot experiment with only 5 subjects per groups. Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Kind Regards,

Synat,

I did not get a proper solutions to my current problems.

Comment: The typical test for multicollinearity is VIF (or the variance inflation factor) test. If VIF is greater than a certain threshold (VIF > 5 is a commonly used threshold), then the variable can be removed if it makes theoretical sense to do so. What programming language/statistical platform are you using to analyse the data?

Comment: Thanks Michael, for your suggestion. I am using R for all my analysis. I have never heard about variance inflation factor. Good to know. if you could suggest further, I am happy to follow and try them all out. Best !